# How to Make Particle Hair Emission Dissipate and Regrow?

Tags: particles, hair

I'm trying to make each individual hair project from the center and dissolve once reaching a set length, all while others are replacing it, in order to keep the structure of the ball.

Tried a keyframing length of hairs but that would carry the entire clump. [image]

Answer (score 0):

I made the render setting "Line" and adjusted some parameters.
[image]